# Linux piping ( convert -> pdf2ps -> lp)

Tags: linux, bash, printing

Ok, so I can print a PDF doing:

```
pdf2ps file.pdf - | lp -s
```

But now I want to use `convert` to merge several PDF files, I can do this with:

```
convert file1.pdf file2.pdf merged.pdf
```

which merges *file1.pdf* and *file2.pdf* into *merged.pdf*, target can be replaced with '-'.

**Question**

How could I pipe convert into `pdf2ps` and then into `lp` though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`convert file1.pdf file2.pdf - | pdf2ps - - | lp -s`
should do the job.

You send the output of the convert command to psf2ps, which in turn feeds its output to lp.

Comment: This works indeed. However, I just found out convert doesn't properly merge my pdf files. Argh. The content is empty. So, onto posting my next question I guess : >

Comment: Final solution:

`pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output - | pdf2ps - - | lp -s` (after installing pdftk)

Comment: @tonio: You do not seem to be aware that both, `convert` as well as `pdf2ps` employ Ghostscript in the background. So instead of running two different wrappers around the same Ghostscript in a pipeline which would make the input data have to go through Ghostscript two times (if it works ***AT ALL***), you would be better off to run a single Ghostscript command to convert multiple PDF files into one PostScript file or data stream....

Answer (score 0):

You can use /dev/stdout like a file:

```
convert file1.pdf file2.pdf /dev/stdout | ...
```

I use gs for merging pdfs like:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/dev/stdout -f ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since hidden behind your `pdf2ps` command there is a Ghostscript command running (which accomplishes the PDF -> PS conversion), you could also run Ghostscript directly to generate the PostScript:

```
gs -o output.ps      \
   -sDEVICE=ps2write \
    file1.pdf        \
    file2.pdf        \
    file3.pdf ...
```

Note, that older GS releases didn't include the `ps2write` device (which generates PostScript Level 2), but only `pswrite` (which generates the much larger PostScript Level 1). So change the above parameter accordingly if need be.

Older Ghostscript versions may also need to replace the modern abbreviation of `-o -` with the more verbose `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/dev/stdout`. Only newer GS releases (all after April 2006) know about the `-o` parameter.

Now, to directly pipe the PostScript output to the `lp` command, you would have to do this:

```
gs -o -              \
   -sDEVICE=ps2write \
    file1.pdf        \
    file2.pdf        \
    file3.pdf ...    \
| lp -s <other-lp-options>
```

This may be considerably faster than running `pdftk` first (but this also depends on your input files).

Answer (score -1):

```
convert file1.pdf file2.pdf merged.pdf
pdf2ps merged.pdf - | lp -s
```