# Merge / convert multiple PDF files into one PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, merge, command-line-interface

How could I merge / convert multiple PDF files into one large PDF file?

I tried the following, but the content of the target file was not as expected:

```
convert file1.pdf file2.pdf merged.pdf
```

I need a very simple/basic command line (CLI) solution. Best would be if I could pipe the output of the merge / convert straight into `pdf2ps` ( as originally attempted in my previously asked question here: [Linux piping ( convert -> pdf2ps -> lp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507596/linux-piping-convert-pdf2ps-lp) ).

Comment: ymmv, but this doesn't seem to have as good of a resolution in the output file as pdfunite and it also results in a file size larger than the output from pdfunite

Comment: related: [linux command merge pdf files with numerical sort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23643274/395857)

Comment: Whenever links are preserved or not by those solutions is discussed [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531215/34551). If you want to preserve the links (probably along with other annotations), use

    pdftk if want a command-line interface,
    pdfsam if you want graphical user interface,
    sejda if you want a web interface.

Comment: The `convert` command line is from ImageMagick and it converts the PDF to an image before doing whatever else it will be doing.

Comment: `pdftk PDF1.pdf PDF2.pdf cat output PDF3.pdf` works fine

Comment: if you want a GUI, you could use "pdfarranger"

Comment: Using a CLI is not bash programming tho (even tho lot of people using `bash` tag seem to believe that). For example lauching `pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf` is no coding. Neither in bash nor in any language. `test -e $outputfile && pdfunite etc`, could be an answer to a bash question, if the question was about `&&` or how can we do something only when some other thing succeeds. But it is not really the case here. The question is about usage of pdf manipulation program. Used with GUI or CLI, that is still just using a program, not coding it.

Comment: See [SuperUser: Stitch multiple PDF's together](https://superuser.com/questions/222849/stitch-multiple-pdfs-together/1807738#1807738)

Comment: Better late than never:  `convert file1.pdf -adjoin file2.pdf merged.pdf` adds the pages from `file2.pdf` to the end of `file1.pdf` and outputs that to `merged.pdf`.  As seen on Fedora 38

Answer (score 669, accepted):

I'm sorry, I managed to find the answer myself using google and a bit of luck : )

For those interested;

I installed the pdftk (pdf toolkit) on our debian server, and using the following command I achieved desired output:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output output.pdf
```

OR

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf ...
```

This in turn can be piped directly into pdf2ps.

Comment: Using ghostscript also might work:  `gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf ...`

Comment: I'd have to look more into the possible options/flags (because I don't want output in a file), but probably yes. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It is worth to mention that pdftk can merge encrypted pdfs while pdfunite cant

Comment: gives better resolution with pdftk compare to convert in default options.

Comment: `pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output out.pdf` will output the merged file as `out.pdf`

Comment: `pdftk` is not available for EL7 systems due to missing dependency `libgcj`.

Comment: @NateKohn @IcyFlame Unfortunately it did not work for me - said `Unknown device: pdfwriter`. Like you I preferred that approach because I had it installed already. `pdftk` worked like a charm though.

Comment: If you don't want to type each file name : `pdftk ``ls *.pdf`` cat output out.pdf`

(with just one backticks instead of two, but I didn't manage to render it with the stackoverflow markdown parser)

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste You can use two backticks as surrounding backticks if you want to use backticks inside. Or three, if you want to use double backticks. Not sure if it goes even higher. But backticks is not recommended anymore in Bash, so better would be to use `$(ls *.pdf)`

Comment: @alcohol What does the `cat` in this command (not in general) do? I was able to merge two pdfs without that and don't see any issues with the resulting pdf.

Comment: @Zelphir cat is the operation here (that pdftk performs), not the shell command.

Comment: `pdftk` is neat because you can easily [select page ranges](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) to merge: `pdftk A=file1.pdf B=file2.pdf cat A1-3 B1 output out.pdf`

Comment: For my usage, `pdftk` somehow just stuck and not producing anything, while `gs` gives perfect result. `convert`'s resolution download is true (with default setting).

Comment: Since `GCJ` is deprecated [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GCJ)), `pdftk` is as well (most distros phased it out already). A nice alternative is `pdfunite` and the other poppler-utils.

Comment: `gs` for joining documents apparently created under Windows gave me this error `Missing glyph CID=48, glyph=0030 in the font EAAAAB+Tahoma,Bold . The output PDF may fail with some viewers.` and indeed, on the default Ubuntu viewer I couldn't browse it

Comment: *The version from the official website doesn't work*. [This answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750883/pdftk-hanging-on-macos-sierra) as of January 2019 (still official).

Comment: A note about **PDF Forms**. Thusfar, `pdftk` is the only tool I have tried that preserves my PDF forms exactly as they were (functional in any PDF reader *plus* Acrobat Reader).

Comment: `pdftk` is deprecated and no longer available in Fedora repos for example.  If you can't use `pdfunite` cause encryption, then try pdf-stapler:  https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler/

Comment: `pdftk` also allows to duplicate pages within a single document : `pdftk input.pdf cat 1-10 10 10 10 10-20 output output.pdf` would produce `input.pdf` with 5 times the page 10.

Comment: `pdftk` is a hell to install

Comment: What is the command for papersize A4? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Pdftk is old, buggy, and not well maintained. It uses a fork of the iText library that is buggy. It has poor error handling and can fail on pdf 1.5 input files. Qpdf is a higher-quality alternative for most of its functionality.

Comment: `pdftk` worked when `pdfunite` did not. `pdfunite` erroneously removed metadata fields from a fillable PDF, [as I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf#comment126379214_11280219). `pdftk` did not--it performed correctly.

Comment: This was orders of magnitude faster than ghostscript for concatenating PDFs, at least on my machine.

Answer (score 2048):

Considering that [`pdfunite`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pdfunite.1.en) is part of [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) it has a higher chance to be installed, usage is also simpler than [`pdftk`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pdftk.1.en):

**⚠ IMPORTANT: Just make sure you remember to provide `out.pdf`, or else it will overwrite the last input file in your command ⚠**

```
pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf in-n.pdf out.pdf
```

A safer solution may include a test of non-existence
targeting the output file

```
export output_file=out.pdf && \
! test -e $output_file && \
pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf in-n.pdf $output_file
```

Comment: Poppler is also very fast, from my tests

Comment: It is fast, but it seems to break hyperlinks. See http://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/8/14/merge-multiple-pdfs/

Comment: Just make sure you remember to provide out.pdf, or else it will overwrite the last file in your command, sigh.

Comment: package for pdfunite is poppler-utils in debian but may not be present in old debian releases.

Comment: Cannot recommend this. The size of the the resulting PDF is far too big. For example: Pdfunite gives me a 75MB file while Ghostscript packs everything into 1MB.

Comment: Hmmm... @Torben I just packed 300+ pdfs (total of 13MB) into a single PDF using this utility and I got a 12MB file at the end.  Maybe it was the version you used?  I am on OpenSUSE 12.2, using pdfunite version 0.20.0.

Comment: @Aaaron My comment was a bit misleading. What I meant is that pdfunite doesn't optimize the filesize. For example: 10 similar pdfs (slides for a presentation) of 1MB result in a ~10MB pdf when I use pdfunite. With ghostscript the resulting pdf is <1MB.

Comment: In my case pdfunite did not produce a usable PDF file. When I loaded it with `evince` I got lots of errors. The `gs` solution worked.

Comment: You can use: `pdfunite *.pdf out.pdf` assuming no other pdf exists in that directory and their order is preserved by "*". If its not preserved, using ranges: filename_{0..9}.pdf solves it.

Comment: pdfunite worked much worse for my use case than pdftk. I was trying to combine together copies of a particular form into the same pdf. In pdfunite they were linked, in pdftk they were separated and could be filled out individually.

Comment: @Torben The file is smaller with gs because with default settings image has reduced quality (screen-view-only quality, 72 dpi images). With `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` file size is almost identical (high quality, 300 dpi images).

Comment: @MariuszS Even though you might be right for some special cases, you're wrong with you're general assumption. I just merged 133MB of PDFs (84 files exported from Inkscape), which contain bitmaps, vectorgraphics and text, into one PDF with a size of 1.6MB. I used `/prepress` for that and `/printer` even reduced the size to 1.3MB. Even though I zoomed in and printed a part, I couldn't find any visible difference between the single PDF and the merged version. I'm pretty sure Ghostscript compares the merged PDFs and stores shared content just for one time.

Comment: @DaniloBargen `pdfunite` doesn't break external hyperlinks. I have merged documents with links. Links were kept functional. But `pdfunite` might break internal hyperlinks as indicated in the [blog you mentioned](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/8/14/merge-multiple-pdfs/).

Comment: pdfunite worked well for me. preserved resolution of original pdfs. pdf size simple addition of original pdfs. convert -compress lossless did the same as convert, resolution lost and file size much increased. pdfunite version 0.22.1 vs ImageMagick 6.7.8-9. 69k + 130k pdf => 198k with pdfunite, => 771k with convert. text+gfx(originally odt) + gfx(pdf print to pdf) pdf.

Comment: Doesn't work with a pdf I have gives `Unimplemented Feature: Could not merge encrypted files ('MR1418_introduction.pdf')`.  But `pdftk` was able to handle it, albeit admonishing me for not having some passwords you don't need.

Comment: Incredibly much faster than `convert`, and the resolution does not get worse. TOP

Comment: Still works to perfection. I didn't see any size change either; 9.2 mb of files made a single 9.2mb file. Didn't have any hyperlinks, so can't comment on that aspect.

Comment: Just put the following in a bash script: `pdfunite $@ out.pdf`

Comment: @AaronR Happy to report working well on openSuse Leap 42.3. Its speed is quite blazing, combining 100-odd pages in less than a second.

Comment: Breaks hyperlinks.

Comment: It seems that page numbers from individual documents are also not preserved. (pdfunite version 0.73.0)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`

Comment: WATCH OUT! The last input parameter is where the program writes the output, so if you accidentally forget `out.pdf` and do `pdfunite in1.pdf in2.pdf` instead of `pdfunite in1.pdf in2.pdf out.pdf`, you'll have just accidentally written `in1.pdf` right on top of `in2.pdf`, ruining it! Don't do that.

Comment: Different pages size, want to "shrink to fit"? Try another tool included in poppler: `pdftocairo -pdf -paper A4 in.pdf out.pdf` ... and make backups as people point out you can override inputs

Comment: I did not find that pdfunite created unreasonably large files.  My two input files were both about 500k and the resulting output file was about 1 MB as one would expect.

Comment: I was fast to use it and not read the comments, so it overwrote the last file. Silly me run "pdfunite *.pdf" and then wondered where's the output file until I realized... Luckily I had a backup; It's always a good idea to have a backup.

Comment: "Likely to be installed" depends entirely on your Linux distro. It's probably true e.g. for Ubuntu and very probably not true for Alpine or Gentoo.

Comment: @bjd2385 An unquoted `$@` is always an error; you want `"$@"`. Without the quotes, it will break on file names which contain whitespace or shell metacharacters.

Comment: `pdfunite` broke my output PDF by deleting entire pages of fields I had filled in [in this PDF here](https://www.schwab.com/resource/custodial-ira-application). I ran `pdfunite in1.pdf in2.pdf out.pdf`. I don't know why it did that, but it must be some issue with the metadata which stores the filled-in text fields inside the fillable PDF, or something. Using `pdftk`, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507825/4561887), however, worked perfectly: `pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out.pdf`.

Comment: I then ran my tool: [`pdf2searchablepdf out.pdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) for good measure, to ensure the PDF metadata fillable fields get turned into an image and then OCRed back into a PDF, in order to remove the metadata fields to ensure I don't have problems printing it at Staples, which also was unable to print properly some of the metadata fields in the original PDF.

Answer (score 781):

Try the good [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/):

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf
```

or even this way for an improved version for low resolution PDFs (thanks to Adriano for pointing this out):

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf
```

In both cases the ouput resolution is much higher and better than this way using convert:

```
convert -density 300x300 -quality 100 mine1.pdf mine2.pdf merged.pdf
```

In this way you wouldn't need to install anything else, just work with what you already have installed in your system (at least both come by default in my box).

**UPDATE #1:** first of all thanks for all your nice comments!! just a tip that may work for you guys, after googleing, I found a superb trick to shrink the size of PDFs, I reduced with it one PDF of 300 MB to just 15 MB with an acceptable resolution! and all of this with the good ghostscript, here it is:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dDetectDuplicateImages -dCompressFonts=true -r150 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

**UPDATE #2:** In case you need to "burn" edits and compress a PDF made with Acrobat, this would help:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=144 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=144 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=144 -sOutputFile=compressed.pdf withedits.pdf
```

Comment: Nice tip, `gs` runs very fast and it compresses a lot. However, the quality improved a lot after I used this param: `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress`

Comment: I found that `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` has the very nice effect of rotating pages that are too wide and force annoying horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: Add the following line to your `.bash_profile` and you have a nice shortcut: `pdfmerge() { gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=$@ ; }` This saves you some typing, if you have to use the command a lot. The usage looks like this: `pdfmerge merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf`

Comment: I tried to find description for -dBATCH flag but couldn't. Even man gs doesn't say anything. But great and without any additional programs!

Comment: Since Imagemagick is based upon Ghostscript, if you already have it, you can use it as well; `convert file1.pdf file2.pdf outputfile.pdf`.

Comment: @RobertSmith Interestingly, when I tried the first command it rotated some pages (that seemed to be the same proportions as the others) while the `/prepress` version did no rotation.

Comment: I like this solution because it keeps section headers that I can use to jump around with my pdf software

Comment: Beautiful answer.  I was having a ton of frustration ever since I heard Mac's Preview application could help, but I barely got it to work the first time, and none the second time I needed it.  The biggest trouble was it not being determinant with its actions.  I used to be able to drag entire PDF files over, but tried invidiual thumbnails, and also had saving issues between a new copy and at all!  So this solution was a nice break.  The only additional task I had was throwing in a GIF image at the end using Preview since Ghostscript could not handle that.  Also installed from Homebrew!

Comment: This preserves hyperlinks. Nice!

Comment: I'm just gonna run this command so that it will be saved to my fish history! I'll definitely need it in the future.

Comment: @Winny, for me it didn't preserve hyperlinks. any idea why?

Comment: @EnanAjmain I used `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=output.pdf a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf` This worked for me

Comment: I used it too. But in my case it didn't work. I then used an online service. Thanks for replying.

Comment: The `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf` can be shortened to the `gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -o merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf`. From [Documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#File_output): "As a convenient shorthand you can use the `-o` option followed by the output file specification as discussed above. The `-o` option also sets the `-dBATCH` and `-dNOPAUSE` options. This is intended to be a quick way to invoke `ghostscript` to convert one or more input files."

Comment: This also works well in windows with WSL. Install ghostscript from apt first.

Comment: I was used to `pdfunite`, but it resulted today in a 850 MB PDF (original 24 MB). `pdftk` did it with 44 MB, `gs` with only 32 MB (both with top resolution as far as I can tell).

Comment: Strange enough. After merging with `gs`, some of pages are rotated.

Comment: gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merged.pdf mine1.pdf mine2.pdf
This worked perfectly on cygwin @Win 10 64 bit machine. Thanks

Comment: @Winny I needed to add `dPrinted=false` to preserve hyperlinks. Otherwise it broke the links for all but the first pdf. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245801/local-hyperlinks-broken-after-pdf-processing-with-ghostscript

Comment: Ghostscript does many lossy transformations (e.g. page rotation, image quality degradation and dropping some metadata) during PDF-to-PDF conversion. If you want to have a peace of mind of having all PDF features intact, then don't use Ghostscript.

Comment: @pts sure, or you can just use custom flags, so that ghostscript doesn't use lossy compression. https://superuser.com/questions/360216/use-ghostscript-but-tell-it-to-not-reprocess-images

Comment: @Rainb: The PDF output of Ghostscript is lossy even if it is configured to use lossless image compression, because Ghostscript ignores some PDF features (e.g. interactive).

Comment: Ghostscript tends to fail if with some pdfs, what a shame

Answer (score 163):

This is the easiest solution if you have multiple files and do not want to type in the names one by one:

```
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Comment: qpdf seems to break hyperlinks in the document

Comment: Although difficult to get your head around the complex options to start with, qpdf is a very handy and powerful tool. Online documentation is available [here](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html)

Comment: Came here looking for a `qpdf` solution but didn't want to wade through the documentation yet again to figure it out, thank you.

Comment: Using a shell wildcard is great as long as the order works for you! Check the order first with `echo *.pdf | tr ' ' $'\n'` or so!

Comment: Nice script. You can arrange the order by prefixing each page with "A_", "B_" etc or **simply add `'z'`** if one document is at page 1 and you want it to be at the last page, assuming your files are named with letters and digits, and not starting with 'z'.

Comment: Qpdf is high in quality and actively maintained, which makes it a much better option than pdftk.

Comment: So far, `qpdf` seems to generate the best output where other viewing tools find no errors/issues.

Comment: In the case of an error about encrypted documents try the following first: `ls *.pdf | xargs -I '{}' qpdf --decrypt {} --replace-input`

Comment: I had two files on Mac Monterey, each 1 M resulting in output of 15 M. I then used [`--object-streams=generate`](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/113) and the output size was normal.

Comment: QPDF is great. Use it this way to extract pages 1-10 from input.pdf and save it as output.pdf:

qpdf input.pdf --pages . 1-10 -- output.pdf

Answer (score 57):

Also `pdfjoin a.pdf b.pdf` will create a new `b-joined.pdf` with the contents of a.pdf and b.pdf

Comment: This is nice and succinct, but breaks hyperlinks.

Comment: pdfjoin (pdflatex) fails with files with lots of pages. Failed to merge to 1k pages files.

Comment: pdfjoin breaks annotations or additional non graphics items

Comment: The "URW Palladio L" font became invisible after pdfjoin'ing the pages.

Comment: pdfunite usually works well, but if it says "Unimplemented Feature: Could not merge encrypted files ", pdfjoin is a nice alternative. For whatever reason, pdfjoin doesn't complain of encryption.

Comment: Works for me natively (probably) without any installation on MacOs Sierra (OsX).

Comment: `v2.08` of `pdfjoin` doesn't proper work for me. One of the input PDF-files contains filled forms. But no inputs appear in the result PDF-file.

Comment: `pdfjam` package doesn't include `pdfjoin` script anymore. You can find the script [here](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam-extras)

Answer (score 53):

`pdfunite` is fine to merge entire PDFs. If you want, for example, pages 2-7 from file1.pdf and pages 1,3,4 from file2.pdf, you have to use `pdfseparate` to split the files into separate PDFs for each page to give to `pdfunite`.

At that point you probably want a program with more options. `qpdf` is the best utility I've found for manipulating PDFs. `pdftk` is bigger and slower and Red Hat/Fedora don't package it because of its dependency on gcj. Other PDF utilities have Mono or Python dependencies. I found `qpdf` produced a much smaller output file than using `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` to assemble pages into a 30-page output PDF, 970kB vs. 1,6450 kB. Because it offers many more options, `qpdf`'s command line is not as simple; the original request to merge file1 and file2 can be performed with

```
qpdf --empty --pages file1.pdf file2.pdf -- merged.pdf
```

Comment: So much this. Parabola for instance doesn’t package `pdftk` anymore either because of its dependance on `gcj`, for which support has been dropped I believe. Despite searching for pdf manipulation tools via `pacman -Ss pdf`, I missed this. Thanks for this answer! I should receive way more upvotes, so it shows up right next to suggestions for `pdfunite` or `pdftk`.

Comment: On my fresh install of Linux Mint, this ran in the Terminal window without requiring any installs or path adjustments. Nice!

Comment: This worked perfectly and also gave a clearer merged document that the other commands I tried out. Thanks for the post.

Comment: If pages in the even.pdf file are reversed (typical when you scan on a non-double-sided scanner), you will want to use this instead: `qpdf --collate --empty --pages odd.pdf even.pdf z-1 -- merged.pdf`

Answer (score 38):

You can use the convert command directly,

e.g.

```
convert sub1.pdf sub2.pdf sub3.pdf merged.pdf
```

Comment: This is not lossless.

Comment: You can `convert -compress lossless sub1.pdf sub2.pdf sub3.pdf merged.pdf`, but the resulting file size's could be way too big. I'd suggest `convert -compress jpeg -quality 90 sub1.pdf sub2.pdf sub3.pdf merged.pdf` instead.

Comment: This involves converting everything to raster images, it seems, which is definitely not the best, especially when dealing with text-based PDFs.

Comment: almost a copy of what the OP has described as not working

Comment: Do not use convert for postscript or PDF files unless you go from vector to raster and never go back.  It is hard to overstate what a bad idea this is.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`pdftools`](https://pypi.org/project/pdftools/) from PyPI.

Download the tar.gz file and uncompress it and run the command like below

```
python pdftools-1.1.0/pdfmerge.py -o output.pdf -d file1.pdf file2.pdf file3
```

You should install python3 before you run the above command

This tools support the below

- add
- insert
- Remove
- Rotate
- Split
- Merge
- Zip

You can find more details [on GitHub](https://github.com/stlehmann/pdftools) and it is open source

Comment: This is perfect. Using `gs` (all variants listed above), a simple merge of two PDFs, 2MB and 500Kb, was taking minutes to complete and resulting in a 40MB file! `pdftools` completes instantaneously with identical file size.

Comment: Or you can install it anyway. Total size of dependencies is < 100 kb.

Answer (score 17):

Apache PDFBox
http://pdfbox.apache.org/

PDFMerger
This application will take a list of pdf documents and merge them, saving the result in a new document.

> usage: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFMerger "Source PDF files (2 ..n)" "Target PDF file"

Answer (score 15):

Although it's not a command line solution, it may help `macos` users:

1. Select your PDF files
2. Right-click on your highlighted files
3. Select **Quick actions** > **Create PDF**

Comment: I wonder why it is so low. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [sejda-console](http://sejda.org/), free and open source.
Unzip it and run  `sejda-console merge -f file1.pdf file2.pdf -o merged.pdf`

It preserves bookmarks, link annotations, acroforms etc.. it actually has quite a lot of options you can play with, just run `sejda-console merge -h` to see them all.

Comment: OMHO the best to tool to do these type of tasks

Comment: This is no longer open source

Answer (score 9):

I am biased being one of the developers of PyMuPDF (a Python binding of MuPDF).

You can easily do what you want with it (and much more). Skeleton code works like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
import fitz         # the binding PyMuPDF
fout = fitz.open()  # new PDF for joined output
flist = ["1.pdf", "2.pdf", ...]  # list of filenames to be joined

for f in flist:
    fin = fitz.open(f)  # open an input file
    fout.insertPDF(fin) # append f
    fin.close()

fout.save("joined.pdf")
#-------------------------------------------------
```

That's about it. Several options are available for selecting only pages ranges, maintaining a joint table of contents, reversing page sequence or changing page rotation, etc., etc.

We are on PyPi.

Answer (score 8):

I second the `pdfunite` recommendation. I was however getting `Argument list too long` errors as I was attempting to merge > 2k PDF files.

I turned to Python for this and two external packages: [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) (to handle all things PDF related) and [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) (to do a "natural" sort of the directory's file names). In case this can help someone:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
import natsort

DIR = Path("dir-with-pdfs/")
OUTPUT = "output.pdf"

paths = DIR.glob("*.pdf")
paths = natsort.natsorted(paths)

merger = PdfMerger()

for path in paths:
    merger.append(path)

merger.write(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: "Argument list too long" indicates that you're going over the shell's allocated buffer size for the environment -- it's not actually a limitation of the tool. In such a case, switching to Python may be overkill, since you can just batch:

find input -name \*.pdf | xargs -P1 -n500 sh -c 'pdfunite "$@" output-`date +%s`.pdf' && pdfunite output-*.pdf output.pdf

(This will create batches of 500 files processed serially, make the resulting temporary files sort in the right order, and produce an appropriate output file; you'll need to clean up the temporary files after)

Comment: `pdftools` is a wrapper for PyPDF2. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946530/8211365) answer.

Answer (score 8):

I used qpdf from terminal and work for me at Windows (Mobaxterm) and Linux, for example the command for join A.pdf with B.pdf at new file C.pdf is:

`qpdf --empty --pages oficios/A.pdf  informes/B.pdf -- salida/C.PDF`

If need more documentation
[https://net2.com/how-to-merge-or-split-pdf-files-on-linux/][1]

Comment: This is quite the undervalued answer. The `qpdf` tool is great

Comment: it's true, qpdf is multi platform, portable and possible used at scripts

Comment: for extract qpdf "in.pdf" --pages . 1 -- "out.pdf"

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert all the downloaded images into one pdf then execute

`convert img{0..19}.jpg slides.pdf`

Comment: Do not use convert for postscript or PDF files unless you go from vector to raster and never go back. It is hard to overstate what a bad idea this is.

Answer (score 5):

You can see use the free and open source [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) (disclaimer: I am the author of it).

It is basically a Python interface to the Latex `pdfpages` package.

To merge pdf files one by one, you can run:

```
pdftools --input-file file1.pdf --input-file file2.pdf --output output.pdf
```

To merge together all the pdf files in a directory, you can run:

```
pdftools --input-dir ./dir_with_pdfs --output output.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Bash script which checks for merging errors.

I had the problem that a few PDF merges produced some error messages.
As it is quite a lot trial and error to find the corrupt PDFs, I wrote a script for it.

**The following Bash script merges all available PDFs in a folder one by one and gives a success status after each merge.** Just copy it in the folder with the PDFs and execute from there.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PDFOUT=_all_merged.pdf
rm -f "${PDFOUT}"

for f in *.pdf
do
  printf "processing %-50s" "$f  ..." >&2
  if [ -f "$PDFOUT" ]; then
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158584/ghostscript-to-merge-pdfs-compresses-the-result
    #  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress
    status=$(gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="${PDFOUT}.new" "${PDFOUT}" "$f" 2> /dev/null)
    if [ "$status" ]
    then
      echo "gs ERROR: $status" >&2
    else
      echo "successful" >&2
    fi
    mv "${PDFOUT}.new" "${PDFOUT}"
  else
    cp "$f" "${PDFOUT}"
    echo "successful" >&2
  fi
done
```

example output:

```
processing inp1.pdf  ...                                     successful
processing inp2.pdf  ...                                     successful
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method I use which works and is easy to implement.  This will require both the **fpdf** and **fpdi** libraries which can be downloaded here:

- FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php
- FPDI: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads

```php
require('fpdf.php');
require('fpdi.php');

$files = ['doc1.pdf', 'doc2.pdf', 'doc3.pdf'];

$pdf = new FPDI();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    $tpl = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tpl);
}

$pdf->Output('F','merged.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu merge c.pdf a.pdf b.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/merge

Comment: can be installed with homebrew +1 havent tried yet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join all PDF files in a directory with Ghostscript, you can use find to do just that. Here's an example

```sh
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec gs -o -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=../out.pdf {} +
```

Will find all pdf in current directory, and create out.pdf in parent directory.
Might be useful if they're looking for a quick way for do an entire directory with ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

```
pdfconcat -o out.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf
```

``pdfconcat  is  a  small and fast command-line utility written in ANSI C that can concatenate (merge) several PDF files into a long  PDF  document.''

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of Chasmo, but I preffer to use the advantages of things like

```
convert $(ls *.pdf) ../merged.pdf
```

Giving multiple source files to `convert` leads to merging them into a common pdf. This command merges all files with `.pdf`extension in the actual directory into `merged.pdf` in the parent dir.

Comment: Given how similar this looks to the original question, it seems like this should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround.

Comment: @Silfheed No, it answers the question! Although the answer maybe should have more elaborated.

Comment: Do not use convert for postscript or PDF files unless you go from vector to raster and never go back. It is hard to overstate what a bad idea this is.

Comment: What is the point of using `$(ls *.pdf)` in place of simple wildcard `*.pdf`?

Comment: Additionally with reference to @firegurafiku answer, with `ls *.pdf` wildcard you lose a control over the order of merged files. In an example, the following list: 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf, ..., 10.pdf, ..., 100.pdf will actually be merged like 1.pdf, 10.pdf, 100.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf (due to default Linux way of ordering files - here you have more details about this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/q/22948042/1977012).

Comment: This converts all PDFs to bitmap before merging them together. Not a good solution unl;ess you know that the original files contain only bitmap data

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, useful is you want to select also the pages inside the documents to be merged:

```
pdfjoin image.jpg '-' doc_only_first_pages.pdf '1,2' doc_with_all_pages.pdf '-'
```

It comes with package texlive-extra-utils

Comment: The package name probably refers to a Debian package.

Comment: I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and have `texlive-extra-utils` installed, yet `pdfjoin` is not found on my system. `My texlive-extra-utils` is version 2020.20210202-3. Any idea why this is the case? Are you actually referring to the Debian distribution of texlive? That should be added to your answer.