# Combine PDF with Matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf

Is it possible to merge several PDF's into one PDF document in Matlab while controlling the sequence in which the PDF's are merged?

Example:

I have a folder with PDF's:

```
docu1.pdf
docu2.pdf
docu3.pdf
docu4.pdf
```

I want to merge them to one PDF document with the following page mapping:

```
page 1: docu3.pdf
page 2: docu4.pdf
page 3: docu2.pdf
page 4: docu1.pdf
```

The above order is just an example, I want to be able to control the sequence in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [merge your PDF files in the command line using ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158584/ghostscript-to-merge-pdfs-compresses-the-result), and you can invoke a command line from Matlab using the [system operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html).

Combining the two you could do:

```
command = 'gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf';
[status,cmdout] = system(command)
```