# Parallelize PDF concatenation using GNU Parallel and Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, parallel-processing, concatenation, ghostscript, gnu-parallel

This can concatenate PDFs ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8158584/1429450)):

```sh
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf
```

but it's slow when concatenating hundreds of PDFs.

Is there a way to parallelize PDF concatenation, such as by using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) somehow?

Comment: Probably. Ignoring **GNU Paralllel** for a moment, please show the first 3 `gs` commands you would want to run in parallel so we can discern the pattern of the parameters.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm sure some recursive, divide-and-conquer function could be constructed so that each execution of `gs` just concats two PDFs.

Comment: Please give some indication of what the first 3 commands would be, without **GNU Parallel**. And also indicate whether the PDFs are all in the same directory.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why 3? And, yes, they're all in the same directory.

Comment: I still don't know if you want all 100+ concatenated into a single PDF or if you just want the number reduced by half by pairing them, or which ones to pair with which, or how the output files should be named...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to concatenate all PDFs in a directory into one single PDF.

Comment: Have you tried timing how long it takes to concatenate say 10 PDFs into a single output PDF and then timing how long it takes to make 2 PDFs with 5 in each and then combine the result?

Comment: Have you tried `pdfunite` and/or `pdftk`? https://linoxide.com/merge-pdf-files-linux/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229960/discussion-between-geremia-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: I have deleted my answer as your experiments appear to show that the task is inherently sequential and therefore not parallelisable with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to say this is cheating:

```
pdftk *pdf cat output /tmp/my.pdf
```

But it is waaay faster than `gs`.