# How to print a one page pdf on both front and back side of one sheet

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I have a single-paged pdf (music sheet paper) that I want to print multiple times with a duplex printer on both front and back side of the paper sheets.

What is the easiest way to achieve this (under linux)?

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If so, please move the question or redirect me to the appropriate place.)

Comment: how many times do you want place your music sheet over any side of paper sheet? (front/back); this seems an imposing task to me. Do you want place 2 music sheets on any paper sheet in A4 format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to change your pdf file so that it takes up two pages, and then print the result in duplex mode.

You can convert your pdf to two pages by appending it to itself, probably using one of the answers in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf).

For instance:

```
pdfunite onepage.pdf onepage.pdf twopage.pdf
```

and then print `twopage.pdf`.