# Bash script - Merging Pdfs

Tags: bash, pdf

hi i have a few thousand single paged pdf files in one folder and one single paged pdf(its file name is 2.pdf). I want to merge all the pdfs in the folder with the 2.pdf file. at the end should have all the pdfs in the folder with 2pages and the second page being the contents of 2.pdf. Please assist on this. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge / convert multiple pdf files into one pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

Comment: @user000001 that a different (more complex) question

Answer (score 3):

So for all PDF files of the current directory, except `2.pdf`, we merge `x.pdf` with `2.pdf` as a new file called `new-x.pdf`. So we can use the command given in [merge / convert multiple pdf files into one pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) to do this:

```
cover="2.pdf";
outputDir="output-pdfs/";

mkdir "$outputDir";

for f in *.pdf; do
    [[ "$f" == "$cover" ]] && continue # skip the cover PDF
    pdfunite "$f" "$cover" output-pdfs/new-"$f".pdf;
done
```