# Bash Sort like Windows 'natural sort order'

Tags: bash, sorting, cygwin

I've got a bunch of PDFs that I'm trying to append together, and I've got a program that, given a list of files, will append them to one PDF.

The issue I'm having is that piping the file names to **sort** does not produce the desired order. None of the flags of **sort** give me what I want either. I've got some examples below:

Desired sort order:

```
test1.pdf
test2.pdf
test10.pdf
```

Achieved sort order using **sort**:

```
test1.pdf
test10.pdf
test2.pdf
```

For more info on exactly what constitutes the sort order I desire, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx

Answer (score 68):

Assuming you're using GNU sort, use  the`-V` option:

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
test1.pdf
test2.pdf
test10.pdf
```

Comment: If you use `ls`, you can do `ls -1v`, which gives you this.

Comment: @LaughDonor Thanks.  I don't happen to use `ls` much.

Comment: Unfortunately, -V does not work for the file names that I've got. They're of the form: sec2_pages12-20, sec2_pages21-30 etc... the ls option totally works though, thank you!

Comment: I had to use "gsort" to get Gnu, otherwise no joy.  The gsort -V option gave me exactly my desired sort on file names with 4 underscore-separated numbers e.g. a_b_V1_8_9 then a_b_V1_9_0 then a_b_V1_10_1.  Using ls -1v didn't handle it.

Comment: @jknielse: I just tried your file name examples, and it worked with GNU sort version 8.23.

Comment: Unfortunately [BusyBox `sort`](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#sort) (typical on embedded Linux) doesn't support `-V` option.

Comment: For posterity, natural sort is not included with the `ls` that is part of FreeBSD or OSX as well. (I know, this question is about cygwin..)

Comment: `sort -V` doesn't worked for me with hungarian characters. The solution was installing `natsort` and `PyICU`, then `natsort -lp` is perfect.

Comment: works in git bash!