# Sorting with -k

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have this list:

```
 DI   bpg01001:PGE00  3:1          ------  1           1 (No fault)
 DI   bpg01001:VOL00  2:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:HPR00  3:12         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:HUH00  3:15         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:PWS00  3:14         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:UOL00  3:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:ACO00  2:0          ------  1           1 (Present)
 DI   rcf10001:BDC00  2:4          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:ERR00  2:2          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:ERS00  2:3          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DO   bpg01001:PGS00  1:4          ------  0           0 (Stop)
```

My goal is to sort everything from `1:4` to `3:15` but `|sort -k3` seems to fail in terms of human readings. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: edited ... sort not short

Comment: You forgot to post your `sort` command. Also, it would make sense if you explain which `sort` program you are using (for instance for me: _(GNU coreutils) 8.26_)

Comment: wht is your OS to not have -V for sort tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `sort` on field 3 with version sort option:

```bash
sort -Vk3 file

 DO   bpg01001:PGS00  1:4          ------  0           0 (Stop)
 DI   rcf10001:ACO00  2:0          ------  1           1 (Present)
 DI   rcf10001:ERR00  2:2          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:ERS00  2:3          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:BDC00  2:4          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   bpg01001:VOL00  2:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   bpg01001:PGE00  3:1          ------  1           1 (No fault)
 DI   dca06001:HPR00  3:12         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:UOL00  3:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:PWS00  3:14         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:HUH00  3:15         ------  1           1 (Normal)
```

---

**Update:** if your `sort` doesn't support `-V` then you can try this *work around* solution:

```bash
awk '{print $3 "#" $0}' file | sort -t: -k1n -k2n | cut -d# -f2-

 DO   bpg01001:PGS00  1:4          ------  0           0 (Stop)
 DI   rcf10001:ACO00  2:0          ------  1           1 (Present)
 DI   rcf10001:ERR00  2:2          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:ERS00  2:3          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   rcf10001:BDC00  2:4          ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   bpg01001:VOL00  2:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   bpg01001:PGE00  3:1          ------  1           1 (No fault)
 DI   dca06001:HPR00  3:12         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:UOL00  3:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:PWS00  3:14         ------  1           1 (Normal)
 DI   dca06001:HUH00  3:15         ------  1           1 (Normal)
```

Comment: I tried already but sort: invalid option -- V

Comment: Hmm may be you don't have gnu sort available. It worked for me on OSX `sort` also

Comment: i dont have gnu sort

Comment: @Pavlos, see the comments here regarding some alternatives for `sort -V`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948089/6288065

Comment: @Pavlos: You can try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you `sort` does not support `-V` you can do a decorate / sort / undecorate to achieve what you are describing:

```
awk '{split($3,a,":"); print a[1],a[2],"|" $0}' file | sort -nk1,1 -nk2,2 | sed 's/^[^|]*\|//'

DO   bpg01001:PGS00  1:4          ------  0           0 (Stop)
DI   rcf10001:ACO00  2:0          ------  1           1 (Present)
DI   rcf10001:ERR00  2:2          ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   rcf10001:ERS00  2:3          ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   rcf10001:BDC00  2:4          ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   bpg01001:VOL00  2:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   bpg01001:PGE00  3:1          ------  1           1 (No fault)
DI   dca06001:HPR00  3:12         ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   dca06001:UOL00  3:13         ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   dca06001:PWS00  3:14         ------  1           1 (Normal)
DI   dca06001:HUH00  3:15         ------  1           1 (Normal)
```