# how to extract a sequence of pages from a PDF into a single file using the command line?

Tags: macos, bash, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

On OSX, how can I extract a sequence of pages from a PDF into a single file using the command line? I see that there are commands to split a PDF into separate pages... but I'd like to specify a page range (e.g. pages 24-31) and output a single PDF file.

Comment: Crude way: Split it to separate pdfs & then combine the required ones... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf

Comment: See if this works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf I believe OSX would have ghostscript...

Answer (score 2):

With the pdfbox command line utilities of the pdfbox-app jar file:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFSplit -startPage 24 -endPage 31 yourfile.pdf
```

A result file named yourfile-1.pdf will be created.