# Can iText convert PDF to TIFF image(s)?

Tags: pdf, itext, tiff

Can we use iText library to convert multi page PDF to multi page TIFF?

Comment: No, we don't do PDF to image.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. " Also, was your Google button broken?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: C'mon. This is not necessarily a useless question for iText newbies. Why not just quickly 'answer' it (like in in your comment), instead of commenting? Why even take on the effort to even start campaigning on Twitter for collecting 'close' votes?! If you 'answered' it in the 7 words above (which doesn:t contain any *'opinionated ... spam'* at all), you'd even get a few upvotes, and you would have helped to burn one part of iText's functionality (scope) firmly into any new user's brain...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle When you say "No, that's not possible" in an answer, you usually down-votes. At least, that's my experience. The FAQ on StackOverflow also doesn't encourage questions that can be answered with *Yes* or *No*, and a custom comment to such questions is *What have you tried?* This person's question reveals that no effort was done to find the answer and the question already has 4 close votes (the 3 down-votes are exaggerated; the single up-vote too). Regardless whether answering would be good for iText, let's keep StackOverflow clean!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: You could extend your answer then to *"No, iText's scope is different. It doesn't convert PDF to images at all. It's only for generating new or modifying existing PDF documents. A short description if iText features is at $URL."* That would be short, sweet and useful for new potential users. And wouldn't make StackOverflow unclean at all. IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

You may convert PDF to images using one of the following tools:

- [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm) (cross platform, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358402/712093))
- [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#adjoin) (cross platform and based on `Ghostscript`, with command line `convert -density 300 image.pdf image.tif`)
- [xPDFRasterizer](http://www.glyphandcog.com/XpdfRasterizer.html) (cross platform, commercial, from authors of [xPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html))
- [ByteScout PDF Renderer SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfrenderersdk/index.html) (Windows only, commercial - *Disclosure: I am related to ByteScout*)

Also, you should consider the following important things when converting PDF to TIFF images:

- PDF rendering is the heavy task that requires lot of memory especially if you are rendering high quality images as output (300 DPI or higher)
- Generating TIFF files is also quite a heavy task so you may consider converting each page from PDF file into a separate file and then merge all pages into final TIFF file.
- You may want to preserve original PDF files in addition to generated TIFF images: PDF is the actual replacement for TIFF format and is **better** because PDF is searchable, may contain both image representation and the original text on top, provides much lesser file size and by using embedded fonts provides scalable high quality text printing.

Comment: ImageMagick isn't independently converting PDF to images all by itself. In the background it employs Ghostscript for that job. If Ghostscript isn't available on the same system as ImageMagick, ImageMagick cannot do that conversion...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle thank you! I've added the remark, ImageMagick as separate tool is good anyway as it provides simplier CLI