# merge/combine several PDF files

Tags: linux, windows, pdf

I have two folders having 1000 pdf files each, having identical names.
I need to merge/combine all PDF files with the identical name in the third folder i.e. the resultant folder (folder 3) will contain 1000 files with each file will be the merged form of folder 1 and folder 2 file that had identical name.

Answer (score 0):

1.Within Acrobat, click on the Tools menu and select Combine Files.
2.Click Combine Files, and then click Add Files to select the files you want to include in your PDF.
3.Click, drag, and drop to reorder the files and pages. Double-click on a file to expand and rearrange individual pages. Press the 4.Delete key to remove unwanted content.
When finished arranging files, click Combine Files.
5.Click the Save button.

[this link should explain how to combine/merge PDF’s](https://acrobat.adobe.com/uk/en/acrobat/how-to/merge-combine-pdf-files-online.html)

Comment: is it free as it claims?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: dear,in the above swnario i have to merge one by one.but i want to merge 1000 files on one click

Comment: Try doing a select all

Comment: Or copy and paste them into one file

Comment: I will try and find another answer and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use any command line tool that supports PDF merging to accomplish this task, see [Merge / convert multiple PDF files into one PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) for some of the tools.

Since you want to work on many files, in a standard shell like `bash` you would do something like the following (using `pdftk` as example but substitute it for the tool you want to use):

```
$ mkdir folder3
$ cd folder1
$ for FILE in *; do pdftk "${FILE}" "../folder2/${FILE}" "../folder3/${FILE}"; done
```