# How can I render multiple URL's into a single PDF

Tags: phantomjs, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I'm attempting to open a series of URL's to render the output, then combine into a single PDF using PhantomJS, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this. I'm just using trial and error, but not getting anywhere - hoping somebody knows how to do this.

I'm not completely set on PhantomJS, so if you know of a better command line, node or JAVA tool that would be better, I'm all ears (or eyes in this case).

Here is the code I have that renders a single page. I've tried replicating the open/render, but it always overwrites the PDF instead of appending to it.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    pages = {
        page1: 'http://localhost/test1.html',
        page2: 'http://localhost/test2.html'
    };

page.paperSize = { 
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait',
};

page.settings.dpi = "96";

// this renders a single page and overwrites the existing PDF or creates a new one
page.open('pages.page1', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('capture.pdf');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS renders one web page into one PDF file, so if you can merge several URLs into one html file you could open it in PhantomJS and make a PDF.

But it would be simpler to make several PDFs and then [merge them into one with something like pdfkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) at the end of the script, launching merge command from PhantomJS [child module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/)