# Merging PDFs with phantomjs

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have made an API that takes the input and generate a serverside pdf a/c to the inputs passed using pdf using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).
Which will be then used by the client.

Now, requirements has changed and I want the starting 4 pages of the pdf to be in **portrait** mode and all the other pages after the 4th in **landscape** mode.

But we can only define the orientation for complete pdf.[HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf#options)

So now, I tried to make two separate pdf

1. starting 4 pages with portrait mode.(PDF -1)
2. rest of the pages with landscape mode.(PDF -2)

But I am not able to find a solution for merging those two separate pdfs(PDF -1 + PDF -2). Is there any way to merge multiple pdf using phantomjs.

And also I have made the complete pdf so I do not want to change the plugin and do the complete work again but, it will be fine if there is some other plugin that can solve my scenario I can use that as the only last option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is not a PDF editor, it cannot edit or merge PDF. But you can easily merge files from node just launching a specific program for that in [a child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) and feeding it the two files. For various options of utilities for PDF merging see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

Answer (score -1):

For merging multiple PDFs, use the `pdfkit` and `node-pdftk` packages:

```
// dataFiles pass this as an array of string of your s3 object
// or buffer strings or paths & outputPath as a destination 

async combinePfds (dataFiles, outputPath){
  try {
    await pdftk.input(dataFiles).output(outputPath);      
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

You can find the code here: 
https://github.com/rauniksingh/async-await-html-pdf---s3