# Issue generating pdf more the 500 pages on server with laravel snappy wkhtmltopdf and save file on ASWs3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

Error is coming while we trying to generate a 700 pages pdf file exit code 139 comes and the below error is coming

[===========================================> ] 72%
Error: Failed loading page file:///tmp/knp_snappy64a569cca41b28.20685486.html?page=507&section=&sitepage=507&title=Client Deposits&subsection=&frompage=1&subsubsection=&isodate=2023-07-05&topage=729&doctitle=Client Deposits&sitepages=729&webpage=/tmp/knp_snappy64a569cca11b69.20878406.html&time=13:02:23&date=5 Jul 2023 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)

I m trying to write the pdf and send to the AWS s3, using the laravel snappy.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to generate smaller PDFs (of say, a couple dozen pages at once) and then [combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) them.